Azure Policy check against a known list
I am looking to see if it's possible for Azure Policy to check against a known list (In this case a known list of CIDR ranges) - Had a quick google and nothing stands out.
I'm looking to:
If CIDR range trying to be created is in a static/parameterised map - then deny effect.
I can manage the policy side if it, it's more the known map, and pulling out key/values based on subscription ID, I don't know if is possible.

Azure Policy doesn't directly support fetching subscription-specific data dynamically within the policy definition. You may need to handle this logic outside of Azure Policy, possibly using Azure Functions or other automation tools to fetch the relevant CIDR ranges based on subscription ID and then enforce the policy accordingly.

You can block network resource creation if the CIDR range does not match a specific CIDR range in the policy assignment. Policy assignment


I am looking to see if it's possible for Azure Policy to check against a known list (In this case a known list of CIDR ranges)

The policy checks the creation of subnets with address prefixes that are not in the allowedCidrRanges parameter array. If any range is not in the allowedCidrRanges, it will deny the subnet creation.
    {
      "mode": "All",
      "policyRule": {
        "if": {
          "allOf": [
            {
              "field": "type",
              "equals": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets"
            },
            {
              "not": {
                "field": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets/addressPrefix",
                "in": "[parameters('allowedCidrRanges')]"
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        "then": {
          "effect": "deny"
        }
      },
      "parameters": {
        "allowedCidrRanges": {
          "type": "Array",
          "metadata": {
            "displayName": "allowedCidrRanges",
            "description": "List of allowed CIDR ranges"
          }
        }
      }
    }

Policy assignment:

When attempting to create a subnet with a different range that is not included in the policy parameters, the policy denies the subnet creation.

